# Cant acces my variable from Controller in View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am just started learning laravel and got stuck while practically doing and the issue is i cant retrieve the variable that i defined in my controller.php into one of my view let suppose (myview.blade.php).

I searched over web but cant get bold answer to solve.

Here is the code:

*controller.php*

```
class WelcomeController extends Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function about()
    {
        $name = 'Farrukh';
        return view('about')->with(name,'$name');
    }

}
```

*myview.blade.php*

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Hello {!! $name !!} !</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which route are you hitting and where are you returning 'myview' view file ?

Comment: route::get('about','WelcomeController@about');

Comment: so the 'myview.blade.php' is just a typo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing like  `return view('about')->with('name',$name);`

Comment: Yaa it worked ! Thankyou .. In tutorials it was opposite but who cares

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy please comment on the tutorial and/or tip the author. It's a silly thing for more people to get stuck on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either:

```
return view('about')->with('name', $name);
```

or

```
return view('about')->with(compact('name'));
```

or

```
return view('about')->with('name',"$name");
```

If you used:

```
'$name'
```

PHP will use it literally, so it will assign $name to 'name' but not the value of $name variable